# Conversion between numerical bases going wrong

Tags: c++, binary, hex

I don't have a clue on what is wrong with my program. I just went testing if this would be usable on at least a console application before adding this "experiment"to my project and as you can see I failed.

I made a library that converts a number between numerical bases (so far, only B16 or B2 to decimal). It's a big work-around since I couldn't understand very well how to manage modulus and divisions, but it seemingly worked until a point.

I gave it a 0xFF and it treated it as 0xFF0, the result being 4,080. I gave it a 0x16 and it treated it like a 0x160, the result being 352. It's obvious what is happening, but I don't know why it is. At least, so far, the problem is only being with B16, although B2 did gave me some weird errors as well.

Here is the code (Code::Blocks on GNU compiler):

```
int bin_to_int(char char_digit){
    char_digit = toupper(char_digit);
         if (char_digit == '0') {return 0;}
    else if (char_digit == '1') {return 1;}
    else {return 2;}
}
int hex_to_int(char char_digit){
    char_digit = toupper(char_digit);
         if (char_digit == '0') {return 0;}
    else if (char_digit == '1') {return 1;}
    else if (char_digit == '2') {return 2;}
    else if (char_digit == '3') {return 3;}
    else if (char_digit == '4') {return 4;}
    else if (char_digit == '5') {return 5;}
    else if (char_digit == '6') {return 6;}
    else if (char_digit == '7') {return 7;}
    else if (char_digit == '8') {return 8;}
    else if (char_digit == '9') {return 9;}
    else if (char_digit == 'A') {return 10;}
    else if (char_digit == 'B') {return 11;}
    else if (char_digit == 'C') {return 12;}
    else if (char_digit == 'D') {return 13;}
    else if (char_digit == 'E') {return 14;}
    else if (char_digit == 'F') {return 15;}
    else {return 16;}
}
void conv_todec(int mode_base){
    if (mode_base == 16){std::cout << "\nHex to Dec function";}
    if (mode_base ==  2){std::cout << "\nBin to Dec function";}
    if (mode_base == 16){std::cout << "\nEnter a hex number: ";}
    if (mode_base ==  2){std::cout << "\nEnter a bin number: ";}
    std::string numb;
    std::cin >> numb;
    int str_leg = numb.length();
    int total = 0;
    for(int i(0);i<str_leg;i++){
        if (mode_base == 16){
            if (hex_to_int(numb[i]) == 16){func_erro();return;}}
        if (mode_base == 2){
            if (bin_to_int(numb[i]) == 2){func_erro();return;}}
        }
    int digits[str_leg] = {};
    int j = str_leg;
    for(int i(0);i<str_leg;i++){
    if (mode_base == 16) {digits[i] = hex_to_int(numb.at(i));}
    if (mode_base ==  2) {digits[i] = bin_to_int(numb.at(i));}
    if (mode_base == 16) {total += (digits[i] * power(mode_base,j--));}
    //Somehow the number never had the first digit claiming it as
    //either even or odd, so I tried pre-decrementing 'j' and it
    //worked for some reason I don't know either.
    if (mode_base ==  2) {total += (digits[i] * power(mode_base,--j));}}
    std::cout << "The result is: " << total << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: you `hex_to_int` function is unnecessarily long and inefficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
 int j = str_leg;
```

means that for hex FF, j will be 2. This means that later on when you do `power(mode_base,j--)` to multiply with the first digit, you will be doing `power(16, 2)` (remember that `j--` means take the value of `j`, then subtract one from `j`, but still use the original value). So you will be multiplying the first digit by 256, where you only wanted to be multiplying by 16.

The solution? Start `j` as one smaller.

```
 int j = str_leg - 1;
```

Note, this is why your binary version works when you use `--j` as you are decrementing `j` before you use it. So either use `--j` and `j = str_leg`, or `j--` and `j = strleg - 1`.

Also, work on the modulo parts - it will make your program a lot easier to write.